# Moving border on hover (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I love the buttons on this site - https://veronicaromney.com/

I tried copying the CSS from the site but I am not making it work right.

I do use Elementor, I added the code to the theme (for the button) and then the ID to the button, but what I got is that the button block (entire block) got the CSS and did nothing on hover.

Can you help me build these buttons?

Here is the code I have so far that pretty much isn't working for me.

```css
.mmb-btn { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0 none;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background-color: #e4b067;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: none 0s ease 0s;
    text-align: inherit;
    line-height: 24px;
    border-width: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 12px 33px 11px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
.mmb-btn:before {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    top: 7px;
    left: 7px;
}
.mmb-btn::after {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.mmb-btn:before, .mmb-btn:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 0.25s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

Comment: Can you include your HTML also?

Answer (score 2):

```css
.mmb-btn { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0 none;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background-color: #e4b067;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: none 0s ease 0s;
    text-align: inherit;
    line-height: 24px;
    border-width: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 12px 33px 11px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
.mmb-btn:before {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    top: 7px;
    left: 7px;
}
.mmb-btn::after {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.mmb-btn:before, .mmb-btn:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 0.25s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}
.mmb-btn:hover:before, .mmb-btn:hover:after {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
```

```html
<a id="start-here-btn" class="mmb-btn alignright" href="/contact/"> GET STARTED </a>
```

You were missing `.mmb-btn:hover:before, .mmb-btn:hover:after`.

Answer (score 2):

A quickie because why not. I suggest using `transform` instead of changing the position as it's more dom fluid and semantically cleaner.

Also remember to apply `pointer-events: none` to the pseudo element so you don't get the spazzy behavior when someone hovers the border outside of the button like you see on the other answers provided.

```css
.fancy-btn {
  padding: .5rem 1.5rem;
  background-color: #eee;
  position: relative;
  transition: background-color .5s ease;
}

.fancy-btn:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  pointer-events: none;
  border: red 1px solid;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate(1rem,1rem);
  transition: transform .25s ease;
}

.fancy-btn:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.fancy-btn:hover:after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-color: green;
  transform: translate(0,0);
}





body {
  height: 90vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<a class="fancy-btn">HEY I AM A BUTTON, YAY</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add only the `:hover`pseudo class.

```
.mmb-btn:hover::before, .mmb-btn:hover::after {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
```

```css
.mmb-btn { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    border: 0 none;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background-color: #e4b067;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: none 0s ease 0s;
    text-align: inherit;
    line-height: 24px;
    border-width: 0px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 12px 33px 11px;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
.mmb-btn:before {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    top: 7px;
    left: 7px;
}
.mmb-btn::after {
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.mmb-btn:before, .mmb-btn:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 0.25s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}


.mmb-btn:hover::before, .mmb-btn:hover::after {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 0.25s ease;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com" id="start-here-btn" class="mmb-btn aalignright" href="/contact/"> GET STARTED </a>
```

Comment: These codes work great for CSS. What's happening though is that on hover it's "killing" the link so when you hover, the button isn't working anymore. 
Also it colors the button box, but doesn't change the default button. 
here is what it looks like right now https://paste.pics/d459949e93a3b81beb61adb21548e8e8

Comment: @wolf81 thanks for feedback. but i cant reproduce your problem. the link is not "killing" if you will hover over the link!? can you add the entire necessary code to your question?

Comment: The code you shared is the whole code I put into Elementor "Additional CSS" box on the button element only. 
The button still looks as default (red) the new styling applied to the entire button section not just button itself. 

When I hover the black like border does move onto the orange rectangle but there is no link in that area, even though it is set up in button settings.

Comment: I figured it out. I need to use a Text/Link for this to work, not the button element!

Comment: @wolf81 all right! thanks for feedback!